# QTest, and void Functions

Tags: c++, qt, unit-testing, testing, qt-creator

I'm approaching to Unit testing for the first time in QtCreator, and I wonder how I can Test functions that does not have a return type.
Like:

rgb_process.h:

```
class RGB_process : Process
{
public:
    RGB_process(cv::Mat& src, cv::Mat& dst, int exp = 0, double c = 1, int r = 0, int g = 0, int b = 0);

    virtual void doProcess() override;

private:
    int exposure_Val;
    double contrast_Val;
    int red_Val;
    int green_Val;
    int blue_Val;
};
```

rgb_process.cpp:

```
#include "rgb_process.h"

RGB_process::RGB_process(cv::Mat& src, cv::Mat& dst, int exp, double c, int r, int g, int b)
    : Process (src, dst), exposure_Val(exp), contrast_Val(c), red_Val(r), green_Val(g), blue_Val(b){
}

void RGB_process::doProcess(){

    for(int i = 0; i < src.rows; i++)
        for(int j = 0; j < src.cols; j++)
            for(int k = 0; k < 3; k++){
                if(k == 0)  //_R
                    dst.at<cv::Vec3b>(i,j)[k] = cv::saturate_cast<uchar>((src.at<cv::Vec3b>(i,j)[k] + exposure_Val + red_Val )*(259 * (contrast_Val + 255) / (255 * (259 - contrast_Val))));
                if(k == 1)  //_G
                    dst.at<cv::Vec3b>(i,j)[k] = cv::saturate_cast<uchar>((src.at<cv::Vec3b>(i,j)[k] + exposure_Val + green_Val )*(259 * (contrast_Val + 255) / (255 * (259 - contrast_Val))));
                if(k == 2)  //_B
                    dst.at<cv::Vec3b>(i,j)[k] = cv::saturate_cast<uchar>((src.at<cv::Vec3b>(i,j)[k] + exposure_Val + blue_Val )*(259 * (contrast_Val + 255) / (255 * (259 - contrast_Val))));
            }
}
```

I can't find any kind of examples on the net, similar to my needs.

Comment: You can check output parameters.

Comment: BTW, you can get rid of if in last loop: either get rid of loop and directly write `dst.at<cv::Vec3b>(i,j)[0] = /*..*/[0] + exposure_Val + red_Val * /*...*/; dst.at<cv::Vec3b>(i,j)[1] = /*..*/[1] + exposure_Val + green_Val * /*...*/; dst.at<cv::Vec3b>(i,j)[2] = /*..*/[2] + exposure_Val + blue_Val * /*...*/; ` or create array for `red_Val, green_Val, blue_Val`.

Comment: @Jarod42 the If statement is there as each K correspond to a channel, and I also pass values for increase just a single between R G and B channels. A kind of White Balance

Comment: I think you don't get my point, instead of `for (int k : {0, 1, 2}) { if (k == 0) f(k, red); if (k == 1) f(k, green); if (k == 2) f(k, blue);}` you can simply have `f(0, red); f(1, green); f(2, blue)` OR `auto colors[3] = {red, green, blue}; for (int k : {0, 1, 2}) f(k, colors[k]);`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When unit testing a function you shouldn't just verify that its return value is what you expect, you must also verify that the objects you work with inside your functions are manipulated in a predictable way, if possible. In case you're testing a `const` method it might be enough to just verify the return value.

Here for example you're working on the `dst` matrix, so you can verify that it's manipulated as you expect since you're applying a pretty clear process on it.

```
cv::Mat mySrc;
cv::Mat myDst;

// Here insert some data in mySrc matrix

RGB_process(mySrc, myDst);

// Here verify myDst matrix is still untouched

RGB_process.doProcess();

// Here verify myDst matrix contains processed data from mySrc matrix
```

You can do this because your `RGB_process` constructor gets a `cv::Mat&` and doesn't copy the whole matrix.

Comment: Thanks for the tips! but for comparing my Mat attributes, I should do that on my own, Qt Macros like, QCOMPARE, QVERIFY.... will not work in that case right?

Comment: I think you should be able to use `QCOMPARE` directly if you implement an `operator==` for `cv::Mat` but I'm not sure.